# More complicated looping flowchart with rays/branches in Mermaid.js

Tags: javascript, flowchart, mermaid

I am having a problem getting a more complicated flowchart using Mermaid.js library.

I would like to have something like this:

```
A --> B --> C
^     |
|     |
|     ˇ
|     D --> E --> F
|     |
|     |
|     ˇ
|     G --> H --> I
|     |
└-----┘
```

Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just use "A" for A and "B" for B, etc. like `graph LR;
    A-->B;`  No additional data is required. The diagram I have provided shows everything necessary. But you are a program and not a human, so, you cannot know that - at least in 2021.

Comment: That topology entirely possible out of the box without doing anything special. Or do you specifically mean the exact alignment you show here?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNptkD0PgyAQhv8KubkOdXRo4rcmndoRHIhgNREwFocG_O-FqJMyHfc87yV3BlrFOETwmenUo-eLSORejOMGBcEjMcmKtlbi_zZVkg16UDK4W5TitLmGoUWZyY5odormON-TuWcFLpprNbSlKdeNlacxFa72XOVZjesGXbuhjYn0CG4g-CzowNzSxncI6J4LTiByJeMdXUZNgMjVqcvEqOa5G6JmiDo6fvkN6KLV-ydbiPS88EPKBupuKHZr_QPcvWpG) is the solution. You need to add some conditions there.

The Markdown code is here:

```
graph LR
A[A] -->B{B} 
B -->|Condition-1| C[C]
B -->|Condition-2| D{D} 
D -->|Condition-1|E[E]
E -->F[F]
D -->|Condition-2|G{G}
G -->|Condition-1|H[H]
H -->I[I] 
G -->|Condition-2|A
```

Output:
[image]